# Disabling Default Routes on Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net Mvc 5 with C#.

I want to disable default routing in my project. My map routes like;

```
    routes.MapRoute(name: "News",
                    url: "haberler",
                    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index"});


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When a user visits my website's news page, it's like;

```
www.domain.com/haberler
```

But also the user can visit the news page as below;

```
www.domain.com/news
```

I want to remove that `"/news"` or direct to seo-friendly url like; "/haberler"

So how can I disable default routing `(Controller-Name-Convension)` routing?

Comment: To remove the default handling just remove the `MapRoute` with name `Default`

Comment: I don't think disabling is good idea. Instead create custom routes as you want.

Comment: Can someone be polite and tell me why you give minus to my question? It's simple, clean and it's need to be done for seo optimization. Maybe I will code redirection rules with owin startup. But I'm searching a better way to do it.

Comment: What is your default route?

Comment: @BonMacalindong thanks for feedback. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the "default" route, you can add a controller constraint to it

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = @"(Account|Manage|Home)" }                
);
```

Like this,  `/news` will return 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

`www.domain.com/news` will not match in any of your routes hence it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing with this

```
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["NAME ROUTE YOU WISH TO RMOVE"]);
```

Hope this will helps you.